# As I can find the critical points of the function $\int_a^b (y^{2}+2(y')^{2}+(y'')^{2}) dx.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

Hi I'm stuck with a problem, greatly appreciate a suggestion to solve:

As I can find the critical points of the function
$$\int_a^b (y^{2}+2(y')^{2}+(y'')^{2}) dx.$$

Comment: not sure if this helps but $$(yy')' = (y')^2 + yy''$$ so $$y^2 + 2(y')^2 + (y'')^2 = (y-y'')^2 + (yy')'.$$ If only we can write $(y-y'')^2$ as some sort of derivative, the problem would become much more doable.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ both constants (independent of $x$)? If so, isn't this definite integral just a constant function?

Comment: I think that $a$ and $b$ are constants.  The statement is as it mentions.

Comment: @LuisE. it's constant in $x$, but the idea is likely to have a 2-variable function in $a,b$...

Comment: Which course are you taking?

Answer (score 1):

As it is currently written, this function is a constant. What you would really need for this to be a function is something like this:
$$f(x)=\int_a^xy(t)^{2}+2(\frac{dy}{dt})^{2}+(\frac{d^2y}{{dt}^2})^{2}dt$$
where $t$ is a dummy variable. Then, you can use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find:
$$\frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{t \to x}y(t)^{2}+2(\frac{dy}{dt})^{2}+(\frac{d^2y}{{dt}^2})^{2}-\lim_{t \to a}y(t)^{2}+2(\frac{dy}{dt})^{2}+(\frac{d^2y}{{dt}^2})^{2}$$
Evaluating the second limit gets you a constant. Set $\frac{df}{dx}=0$ by definition of a critical point and solve the resulting equation.